# How to monitor the proposal covariance in PyMC?

Tags: python, montecarlo, pymc

I'm testing the `AdaptativeMetropolis` step method in PyMC (as documented [here](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/modelfitting.html#the-adaptivemetropolis-class)), and wish to see it in action. Such a step method consists in block-updating some variables using a multivariate jump distribution whose covariance is tuned during sampling.

It is possible to print the proposal covariance matrix vs time? It looks to me that this is not documented.

Thanks.

EDIT: as a toy model, let us consider the case of two similar dice (let's say that they come from the same factory). We wish to estimate whether they are biased.

```
import pymc
n = 100
alpha = pymc.Gamma('alpha', alpha=1, beta=1)
P1 = pymc.Beta('p1', alpha=alpha, beta=2)
P2 = pymc.Beta('p2', alpha=alpha, beta=2)
Y1 = pymc.Binomial('y1', n=n, p=P1, value=70, observed=True)
Y2 = pymc.Binomial('y2', n=n, p=P2, value=50, observed=True)
model = pymc.Model([alpha, P1, P2, Y1, Y2])
MC = pymc.MCMC(model)
MC.use_step_method(pymc.AdaptiveMetropolis, [P1, P2])
```

I now expect/guess that `P1` and `P2` are set to be sampled using a normal bivariate proposal with adaptative covariace. How can I monitor this? The sampling is done after calling

```
MC.sample(iter=11000, burn=10000)
```

Comment: just curious, how do you envision a covariance matrix being visualized, particularly across time? Is there no way to construct the visual you're seeking once the MCMC is done - like with other traditional plots

Comment: As a very first step it would be enough for me to be able to print it on terminal.

Comment: The block variables that you're updating should be stored in the trace so, you could feed the corresponding traces into the covariance matrix model to see the covariance matrix at steps in the MCMC. Perhaps providing a  model for which we can run MCMC would make people more willing to help

Comment: @GeneBurinsky Thanks for the hint. I added a toy model, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging the [source code](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/blob/03718ef9e1b1f3b812d592d2c06a656d187ae98e/pymc/StepMethods.py#L1264), I found that it is possible to tune the verbosity to print the covariance matrix:

```
if self.verbose > 1:
  print_("\tUpdating covariance ...\n", self.C)
  print_("\tUpdating mean ... ", self.chain_mean)
```

Hence, it should be sufficient:

```
MC.use_step_method(pymc.AdaptiveMetropolis, [P1, P2], verbose=2)
```

Also the final correlation matrix is stored into `MC.get_state()['step_methods']['AdaptiveMetropolis_p1_p2']['proposal_sd']`. This can be used to compute the covariance matrix after the sampling (`np.dot(corr, corr.T)`).